# Evaluate a template on the fly

Tags: javascript, meteor

--USING METEOR FRAMEWORK --

Hi I want to access to the following template via `Template["tViewPost"]`

```
<template name="tViewPost">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <span>{{title}}</span>&lsaquo;&lsaquo;<span>{{subttile}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

And be able to render/evaluate this template with a javascript object like `{ title : "My title", subttitle : "othe subtitle"};` but I dont know how to do it once I have the template in a variable, I would like to do it as underscore library does.[example in [http://underscorejs.org/]](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
var template = _.template("whatever <%= title %>");
var o = {title : "ohhh!"};
$("someDomElement").html(template(o))
```

does its possible to do it? and how? thanks...

Comment: Well, the question is not clear to me. 1. Do you not know how to assign a string literal to a variable? Or is the template code present in some file and you want to be able to read that file on the server and pass it to the javascript on the client side? 2. Do you want to use the underscore's template function or write your own?

Comment: Hi man this is using Meteor framework, Meteor have a global variable named Template which hold all the templates you declare in any html file, then you can access the template via the Template["name of the template"] function. My question is how to use this awesome system but in the underscore way. instead of handlerbars.js which is the template system using by Meteor

Comment: I'm planning to learn Meteor sometime soon. So, I've been checking it out reading documentation online, watching screencasts, etc. I believe , as of now, underscore is packaged along with Meteor. So, you should be able to use methods from underscore.js directly by just writing the templates as you'd write for a normal underscore.js application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try do this using **[Meteor.render](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render)** (from docs):

```
// Client side: show the number of players online.
var frag = Meteor.render(function () {
  return "<p>There are " + Players.find({online: true}).count() +
    " players online.</p>";
});
document.body.appendChild(frag);

// Server side: find all players that have been idle for a while,
// and mark them as offline. The count on the screen will
// automatically update on all clients.
Players.update({idleTime: {$gt: 30}}, {$set: {online: false}});
```

Edited:

```
// returns string which contains html
Meteor.render(Template['name'](dataObject))


// your case:
<template name="test">
   whatever {{title}}"
</template>

var o = {title : "ohhh!"};

$("someDomElement").html(Meteor.render(Template['test'](o)))
```

Comment: I already tried that, but actually the question, is a little different Im trying to emulate the way underscore do it. over an string. Evaluate it with an object on the fly.

Comment: Post updated with example similar to underscore one.

Comment: ohh thank man I will try in a couples minutes ...if work for sure you get the right answer :D